# Looping Dates in Teradata

Tags: loops, teradata

I have a very large query which returns about 800,000 rows on a monthly basis
I have been asked to run it for the year but obviously this will not all fit into a single excel file. Unfortunately the details are necessary for the analysis being undertaken by the business analyst so i cant roll it up to aggregates

```
SELECT * FROM foo where foo.start_date >= 20150101 AND < 20150201
```

I was wondering is it possible in Teradata to set up a loop to run the first query, increment the time period for a month, export it as a text file then run the query again

I would be using Teradata SQL Assistant for this with the export functionality

I could run it for the year and split it in MS Access afterwards but i would just like to see if there is a way to implement it directly in Teradata

Thank you for your time

Comment: Have you considered your scripting options with BTEQ for Windows and PowerShell?

Comment: That sounds like a good approach.  I will try it. I thought teradata had its own way of looping

Comment: Actually, check the Command Line options in the Help file for SQL Assistant. You may be able to accomplish what you like without having to fiddle with PowerShell and BTEQ. Forgot about those options to run SQL Assistant in a "batch mode".

Comment: Is it a semi-manual activity or you have to make it completely automatic? In the former case, you might create a query to create the SQL for all the periods you need, then launch it with the export functionality (text file). If I'm not wrong if you launch more than one query with the export function of SQLAssistant, it will create as many files as the queries, with a progressive suffix (e.g. result.txt, result2.txt, result3.txt, etc)